# Deploy webapp to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've manually deployed my web application to AWS EBS.  We use to normally have a jenkins pipeline which deployed the app to tomcat server running on AWS using mvn tomcat8:redeploy-only -Ddeploy.address=xx.xx.xx.xx:port

How do you deploy to AWS EBS with Jenkins, at the moment I'm having to upload the war file each time we have an update.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, but there is a Jenkins plugin for [Elastic Beanstalk](https://plugins.jenkins.io/awseb-deployment-plugin/).

Alternatively, you could install [elb cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) in your Jenkins nodes to manage your environments.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the plugin now successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I used AWS Beanstalk publisher jenkins plugin which allowed me to set up post-build actions which was the answer.  You need to specify S3 bucket in the settings of where your app will be deployed to and set up version labelling.  Thanks for kgiannakakis for referring this to me.

A good video I used can be found here: [deploy war file to aws ebs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRXrS1dSfSs)